# Resetting the validation in Xamarin.Forms after invalid entry

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin form I'm validating date of birth

`public ICommand ValidateDOBDateCommand => new Command(() => DateOfBirth.Validate());`

Then I use binding in the XAML page.

With an invalid entry the submit button is disabled and an error message is displayed.

But I've noticed that when a an invalid entry has been entered, the submit button is disabled, but after the entry is corrected, the error message is still displayed and the submit button is still disabled.

What is the pattern used when using `.validate()` to detect if the entry has been corrected by the user and reset the validation and enable the submission.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/validation-xamarin-forms-enterprise-apps/

Comment: I think we need to see a lot more of your validation code

Comment: @SparshaBhattarai That's a great reference, I read : "Property change notification is provided by the ExtendedBindableObject class, and so an Entry control can bind to the IsValid property of the ValidatableObject<T> instance in the view model class to be notified of whether or not the entered data is valid."     but I'm not sure if this resets the IsValid property for me.

Comment: For every ValidatableObject, on the value change event, the validate() function is triggered, which in turn sets or clears the errors and triggers the IsValid property. That's the concept for validations. So, it should work in your case. Again, can't say much without seeing your code.

Comment: Yes, I see that the IsValid has a .clear() method

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not `disable` the `Submit Button`. Just show the `error message` on wrong entry and `success message` on correct entry.

If you insist on disabling the `Submit Button`. Than I would suggest to use `ReactiveUI`. It have features to enable such scenarios. But using it is a steep `learning curve`.